# How to propogate null instance in C#/MVC without If/Else or Try/Catch?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, json.net, nullreferenceexception

I have an entry in Razor View which is

```
<li data-img-url="@stock["images"][0]["url"]">
@* stock is a JObject which can contain or cannot contain ["images"]*@
```

Irrespective of location of null occurence, how to get the final string `data-img-url=""`. Also how to handle such situations where output of statement is needed without adding extra code blocks such as `If/Else` or `Try/Catch`

Comment: Just create a function that gets the URL and has the if/else logic in it.

Comment: Try applying it like

@stock?["images"]?[0]?["url"]">

Comment: @Conrad, answer with too many questions :)

Comment: I am using the null-propagating operator to avoid accessing null object properties and variables hence avoiding the null reference exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JObject` has a `SelectToken` method which you can utilize for your scenario.

```
  JObject jsonDoc = JObject.Parse(json);

  Console.WriteLine(jsonDoc.SelectToken("images[0].url"));
```

[Here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm) you will find reference code for SelectToken

*SelectToken will return empty if no token found and return results if its a valid result*

Answer (score 1):

In *just* C#, the null-propagating operator can help here, i.e.

```
var x = obj?["bar"];
```

note however that this only deals with *nulls*; it won't help you if the problem is a `KeyNotFoundException` (because `obj` isn't `null`, but there's no key `"bar"`). So: in the general case: just write a method that *does what you need*, and which also makes everything cleaner; this could be an extension method on whatever `stock` is, noting that extension methods *do not null check* on the `this` argument:

```
public static string GetFrob(this Stock stock, string grapple, int foo, string blap)
{...}
```

...

```
<li data-img-url="@stock.GetFrob("images", 0, "url")">
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I have understood the question well, but according to what you want to do you have to put an if:

```
@(stock["images"][0]["url"] == null ? "" : stock["images"][0]["url"])
```

it is an if, but with linear syntax

Answer (score 0):

Use a ternary:

```
<li data-img-url="@(stock["images"][0]["url"]! = null:stock["images"][0]["url"]:"""> @* stock is a JObject which can contain or cannot contain ["images"]*@
```

If the doesn't work, encase the entire attribute in the ternary.